# Configuring Vue and Webpack in Vuepress app

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuepress

In my Vuepress project I would like to use [v-runtime-template](https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template).

Their setup instruction says

> You must use the with-compiler Vue.js version. This is needed in order to compile on-the-fly Vue.js templates. For that, you can set a webpack alias for vue to the vue/dist/vue.common file.

This could be achieved by adding

```js
module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true
};
```

to `vue.config.js`, but I do not understand how to configure in Vuepress.

I tried this:

```js
// .vuepress/enhanceApp.js
export default ({ Vue, options, router, siteData }) => {
  Vue.config.runtimeCompiler = true
}
```

but it did not give any results.
How should the configuration be done?

Answer (score 1):

From: https://github.com/vuejs/vuepress/issues/402#issuecomment-388169056

Add the following to your `.vuepress/config.js`:

```js
chainWebpack(config) {
  config.resolve.alias.set('vue', 'vue/dist/vue.common.js')
}
```

More info: https://vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#chainwebpack